# Passing variables between KnockoutJS and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js

1. I am using Knockout in my SPA dashboard creation. Its working good.But we need to add more and more complex things in our dashboard, so we planned to develop the remaining part of dashboard in Angular.
2. My question is how can i pass variables from knockout to Angular. I tried using set and get methods, but it didn't helped me..
   3.So, i tried like this, i would like to set an attribute value in the ko function when, like this..

```html
<li id="setMgmtEnv">
  <a href='javascript:;' data-bind="click: setMgmtEnv">
    <span>Manage Orgs</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

```js
///////in Main JS file
var x = document.getElementById("setMgmtEnv"); 
        x.setAttribute("value", "0");
    ////// In KO model
    self.setMgmtEnv =  function(){
                x.setAttribute("value", "1");           
            }
    ///////// In Angular i am noticing the change variable like this
   $scope.$watch(function(load) {
    return $scope.toLoad = document.getElementById('setMgmtEnv').value;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("$scope.toLoad2 : " + $scope.toLoad);
    if ($scope.toLoad) {
        console.log("$scope.toLoad3 : " + $scope.toLoad);
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : url
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data) {
            alert("Failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
                data : data
            }));
        });
    }}
```

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for a mess and a large technical debt - I would either figure out how to make it work in knockout, or plan for a rewrite using angular.

Comment: I don't see a need for Angular. Can you elaborate on why you think you need that? I would just break up the app into Knockout components.

Comment: It's really not clear when you post code in comments - if there's a specific issue you're having with adding some functionality in knockout, you can [edit] your question with more details.

Comment: Plz check the updated question

Answer (score 7):

Mixing KnockoutJS and AngularJS in one application is a big red flag. Be sure you understand what you're doing, or you'll probably be better off rewriting the KO parts in Angular.

Having said that, I can try to answer the question you're asking, though not in the context of the code snippet you provided (which is *very* unclear).

There are three main ways KO can interact with Angular (which is the direction you seem to be asking about):

1. They each control their own piece of the DOM. KO will "notify" Angular through Javascript code. This would be the preferred situation.
2. They each control their own piece of the DOM. KO will "notify" Angular by influencing a piece of the DOM actually controlled by Angular.
3. They have shared control of the same piece of the DOM. KO "notifies" Angular automatically because it will update the DOM when a variable changes, and Angular's two-way bindings pick this up.

Option 2 and 3 are a recipe for disaster. They *can* be done, but are that bad I'll leave creating a PoC as an excercise for the reader.

That leaves option 1, which in specific cases can actually be useful. To do so you need these ingredients:

- Within Angular's scope a reference to the KO ViewModel;
- A subscription on the relevant part of KO's ViewModel;
- A call to `$scope.$apply` no notify Angular the KO subscription callback has changed the scope.

Here's an exmaple:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.name = ko.observable("");
};

var vm = new ViewModel();

angular.module("demoApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.name = vm.name();
  
    vm.name.subscribe(function(newVal) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.name = newVal;
      });
    });
  }]);

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("knockoutArea"));
```

```css
div { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #edd; background-color: #fee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="knockoutArea">
  <strong>Knockout</strong><br>
  Type your name: <input data-bind="textInput: name">
</div>

<div id="angularArea" ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <strong>Angular</strong><br>
  We know your name is: <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
</div>
```

As an alternative, given that Angular seems to be your way forward, you may want to invert the dependency. Give KO a reference to Angular and make that "legacy" part of your code call updates on the Angular scopes. This makes your KO code a lot dirtier, but keeps your future codebase cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen... This really helps me. Will get back once I implement part 1 of ur process.

Comment: @ShankarP Ok, good to hear. Good luck, and let us know how you solved things in the end.